# Tailwind Border not working while switching preflight mode to false

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

Why does the `border` in my code below not work if I switch preflight to `false`?

```
<div class="border border-gray-300 w-[50px] h-[50px]"></div>
```

Comment: Could you create a [reprex]?

Comment: Have you tried adding a border style, e.g. `border-solid`?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.